# Can only display information about the last created object | Overwrites previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a system where I can create some "houses" and "people". The next step for me, is that I want to display some information about the house that I click on. However, I can only access the information about the last of the houses that is created, not mather on what house I click.

See the image here:

[image]

The house on the right is the last house that I've created. The informations displays correct. But if I click the first house (the one on the left), my information won't change.

I have created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Adnaves/pcVR6/1/) here where our can try it our for yourself.

I'm guessing that my problem lies somewhere in my objHouse.click(function(). I've tried several different ways. Right now I'm trying to target it like this:

```
$('#BtnCreateHouse').click(function(){
oHouse = CreateHouseInMemory();
CreateHouseInLayout(oHouse);


});

function CreateHouseInMemory()
{
var oHouse = 
{
    "id":   "H"+GetRandomNumber(999, 999999999999),
    "StreetMame": $('#StreetName').val(),
    "Number": $('#Number').val(),
    "MaxPeople" : $('#MaxPeople select').val(),
    "aPeople": []
}
aHouses.push(oHouse);
console.log(oHouse); 
return oHouse;  
}

function CreateHouseInLayout()
// See JSFIDDLE, to much code to be posted here.


var objHouse = $('#' + oHouse.id)

objHouse.click(function(){
    $("#WindowDisplayHouseInfo").show();                            
    $('#ShowId').text("ID: " + oHouse.id);
    $('#ShowStreetName').text("Street Name: " + oHouse.StreetMame);
    $('#ShowNumber').text("Number: " + oHouse.Number);
    $('#ShowMaxInhabitants').text("Max inhabitants: " + oHouse.MaxPeople);

    for(var i = 0; i < oHouse.aPeople.length; i++)
    {
    $('#ShowInhabitants').html("<br />" + "Inhabitant: " + oHouse.aPeople.length 
                               +"<br />" + "ID: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].id
                               +"<br />" + "Name: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].Name
                               +"<br />" + "Last Name: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].Lastname
                               +"<br />" + "Age: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].Age
                               +"<br />" + "Gender: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].sGender
                               );
    }   

        $('.DeleteHouse').click(function()
        {
            $(objHouse).children().each(function(){
                $(this).appendTo($('#City')).css({"top":"" , "left":""});
            });

            $(objHouse).remove();                  
            $("#WindowDisplayHouseInfo").hide();
        });
});
```

I really hope that one of you can tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong. I've been stuck for hours now.

**UPDATE**

I've found out that if I change:

```
objHouse.click(function(){
```

to

```
$('.House').click(function(){
```

and then change

```
$('#ShowId').text("ID: " + oHouse.id)
```

to

```
$('#ShowId').text("ID: " + this.id);
```

Then it will work for the ID, but if I fx. write ("Street Name: " + this.StreetName); then it won't work. Any idea why?

Updated JSFIDDLE here: http://jsfiddle.net/Adnaves/pcVR6/2/

Comment: That not the problem. 
I can fetch the class .House 's ID by using this.id. But my class .House doesn't have anything called: StreetName. It's my oHouse that has this value. So I'm stuck again.

Comment: var oHouse = {"StreetMame": $('#StreetName').val()} It's right here. Don't mind the typo, it is corrected in my own files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside:

```
$('#BtnCreateHouse').click(function(){
oHouse = CreateHouseInMemory();
CreateHouseInLayout(oHouse);
});
```

You don't define the oHouse var in the function scope and later in the CreateHouseInLayout function you don't use the passed parameter but the global variable from before. So the click function creates a oHouse variable in the global symbol table, which is later accessible by the CreateHourseInLayout and this works fine the first time, but the second time you click you're overwriting the global variable and the first house == the second house. What you need to do is properly scope your variables:

```
$('#BtnCreateHouse').click(function(){
   var oHouse = CreateHouseInMemory(); // Create the house var locally and pass it to the other function
   CreateHouseInLayout(oHouse);
});

function CreateHouseInMemory() {
   var oHouse = {
    "id":   "H"+GetRandomNumber(999, 999999999999),
    "StreetMame": $('#StreetName').val(),
    "Number": $('#Number').val(),
    "MaxPeople" : $('#MaxPeople select').val(),
    "aPeople": []
   };
   aHouses.push(oHouse);
   console.log(oHouse); 
   return oHouse;  
}

function CreateHouseInLayout(oHouse) { // use the passed house object
   var objHouse = $('#' + oHouse.id)

   objHouse.click(function(){
     $("#WindowDisplayHouseInfo").show();                            
     $('#ShowId').text("ID: " + oHouse.id);
     $('#ShowStreetName').text("Street Name: " + oHouse.StreetMame);
     $('#ShowNumber').text("Number: " + oHouse.Number);
     $('#ShowMaxInhabitants').text("Max inhabitants: " + oHouse.MaxPeople);

     for(var i = 0; i < oHouse.aPeople.length; i++) {
       $('#ShowInhabitants').html("<br />" + "Inhabitant: " + oHouse.aPeople.length 
                               +"<br />" + "ID: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].id
                               +"<br />" + "Name: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].Name
                               +"<br />" + "Last Name: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].Lastname
                               +"<br />" + "Age: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].Age
                               +"<br />" + "Gender: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].sGender
                               );
     }
     $('.DeleteHouse').click(function() {
            $(objHouse).children().each(function(){
                $(this).appendTo($('#City')).css({"top":"" , "left":""});
            });

            $(objHouse).remove();                  
            $("#WindowDisplayHouseInfo").hide();
     });
   });
}
```

Keep in mind that withing the CreateHouseInLayout method now the oHouse variable is local and all functions created within that one can access it. So your objHouse.click(function(){}) also has access to that local copy and will display the correct information. Where objHouse is a single element that represents that specific house. If you use the $('.House').click() like you do in the JSFIDDLE example, you're binding the callback to all elements, but with a single oHouse object, so they will all display the same info (i.e. use the objHouse method).

Comment: Thank you so much. And thanks for the explanation on what you did. Now I should be able to also do it on my cars etc.

Comment: Btw. You might have spotted my for loop. If I drag a person on top of my house, I'm supposed to see the information about the people that are living there. But right now it is also just showing me the last person that is put into the house. Do you have an idea on how I can fix it there?

Comment: Same like the other one, the $('.house').droppable is created for all house, but it references only the last one. within the CreateHouseInLayout make sure you bind events only to the specific DOM element, that represents the house. Also to avoid confusion you can store your objects in the elements using jQuery.data. So when you create a person you can do personObj.data('info', oPerson) and than when you to display the information for the house just do objHouse.find('.Person').each(function () { var i = $this.data('info'); ... }); . Maybe try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Gf2c2/1/

Comment: P.S. Getting the people using the html elements appended to the div, is easier, because you don't need to worry about removing an element from the Array when a person is moved to another house.

Comment: Thanks. This might be a bit to complex of a solution for me right now. But it definitely gives me something to go after in the future. :)